# grep value inside a variable pointing to other variable

Tags: unix, scripting, shell

using : ksh
*abc = 1
efg = 2
hgd = 3 not known to me *

say if i have

Value="abc  efg  hgd"

abc efg hgd all contains some value which i dnt know.

Now I want to **grep** the value contained inside abc.

like 
    for i in $Value 
    do 
        grep "`echo $(($((echo $i | cut -d'|' -f2))))`" 
    done

this grep should look for the value inside abc efg hgd

grep 1
grep 2
grep 3

Comment: Can you give an example to show what you are trying to achieve? Your question is not really clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "$(echo $(($(echo $i | cut -d'|' -f2))))"
```

This is working.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use variables like they were meant to be used, i.e instead of

```
Value="abc efg hgd"
```

Say:

```
Value="$abc $efg $hgd"
```